# Casting android.os.IBinder causes ClassCastException once in a while

Tags: java, android, android-service, classcastexception, android-service-binding

I am experiencing a weird `ClassCastException` exception when trying to cast an `IBinder` to a local's service Binder. This happens once in a while, and I personally cannot reproduce it (only know about it thanks to Crashlytics). The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to gr.sport24.radio.MediaPlayerService$MediaPlayerBinder
       at gr.sport24.radio.RadioManager$RadioServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(RadioManager.java:740)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1203)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1220)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
```

---

This is the code that initiates the connection:

```
mApplicationContext.bindService(
    new Intent(mApplicationContext, MediaPlayerService.class), 
    new RadioServiceConnection(), 
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
);
```

---

This is the RadioServiceConnection inner class:

```
private class RadioServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder serviceBinder) {
        synchronized (RADIO_LOCK) {
            // This is the line where ClassCastException sometimes occurs
            MediaPlayerService.MediaPlayerBinder binder =
                (MediaPlayerService.MediaPlayerBinder) serviceBinder;
            mRadioService = binder.getService();
            mRadioService.setClient(RadioManager.this);
        }

        mIsConnectingToRadioService.set(false);
        mIsBoundToRadioService = true;

        if (mAutoStartOnBind) startRadioPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mIsConnectingToRadioService.set(false);
        mIsBoundToRadioService = false;

        stopRadioPlayer();
    }
}
```

---

This is the MediaPlayerService class (slim version):

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service
{
    private final Binder mBinder;
    ...

    public MediaPlayerService() {
        mBinder = new MediaPlayerBinder();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    ...

    public class MediaPlayerBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MediaPlayerService getService() {
            return MediaPlayerService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the BroadcastReceiver that receives local notification button events (a local notification is created in order to play/pause radio):

```
private class LocalRadioNotificationEventBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Static.debug) Log.d(TAG, "Received local radio notification event.");
        if (intent == null) return;

        String action = (intent.getAction() != null) ? intent.getAction() : "";
        if (RadioNotificationEventsReceiver.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE.equals(action)) {
            onRadioNotificationAction(ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);
        } else if (RadioNotificationEventsReceiver.ACTION_CLOSE.equals(action)) {
            onRadioNotificationAction(ACTION_CLOSE);
        } else {
            if (Static.debug) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown radio notification action [" + action + "].");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: `onRadioNotificationAction()` does not do anything fancy, it just checks what action was executed and acts accordingly. If for some reason connection to service is lost, `bindService()` will be called indirectly from this method.

---

This is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="gr.sport24.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="gr.sport24.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/sport24"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sport24"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.sport24.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LiveViewerActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WebViewerPlainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WebViewURLActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WebViewerActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoadingPlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.sport24.Transparent.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TeamSelectorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.PreferenceActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.AboutActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.PreferenceActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.GalleryActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.sport24.TranslusentActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.RadioActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="gr.sport24.radio.MediaPlayerService" />

        <!-- Receiver used for listening to radio notification actions. -->
        <receiver android:name="gr.sport24.radio.RadioNotificationEventsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="gr.sport24.radio.intent.action.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE" />
                <action android:name="gr.sport24.radio.intent.action.ACTION_CLOSE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.pushmyapps.push.GcmMessageListenerService"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.pushmyapps.push.GcmTokenRefreshListenerService"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
        <service android:name="com.pushmyapps.location.GeofencesIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.pushmyapps.sync.SyncService"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="gr.sport24" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="gr.sport24.PushManager$CustomPushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.pushmyapps.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.pushmyapps.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.pushmyapps.push.intent.CLOSE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.pushmyapps.BootUpBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Usually, this crash happens when a service is declared with the `android:process` attribute, which indicates that service will be started in a separate process, but this is clearly not my case.

Is it possible for the `onServiceConnected()` to receive the "wrong" `IBinder` ? I haven't found any evidence of this in the docs though.

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: post your entire manifest please

Comment: I have posted Manifest file

Comment: Where does the call to `bindService()` happen? In what class? in what method?

Comment: You aren't alone :-( See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181164/ibinder-casting-sometimes-results-in-classcastexception-when-binding-to-servic

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that question, but hoped that something has changed after one year :-(

Comment: `bindService()` is called at the start of the app or once user presses a button and the service had not started for some reason until then.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean "at the start of the app"? From an `Activity`? From a `Service`? From a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Initially, it is indirectly called from inside `Application.onCreate()`. After that, it can be called from an `Activity`, a `Fragment` or a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Please post the code from the `BroadcastReceiver` and indicate what triggers the call to `onReceive()`.

Comment: Do you know what devices this occurs on?

Comment: Mostly on Samsung devices (SM-G360F, SM-T530, SM-T535 etc.). Also, it happens only on devices with Android 5.0 and up ...